# ng2-pdf-viewer error : node_modules/ng2-pdf-viewer/node_modules/@types/pdfjs-dist/index.d.ts cannot find unknown name

Tags: ionic3

I am new to ionic. I get the below error while running ionic serve  for the ng2-pdf-viewer package.

[image]

The package version I use is 5.2.3 .

Ionic info:

```
cli packages: (C:\Users\FINWISELY\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.3

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.4
    Cordova Platforms  : android 7.1.4
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.9

System:

    Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
    Node              : v12.13.1

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.4
    Cordova Platforms  : android 7.1.4
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.9

System:

    Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
    Node              : v12.13.1
    npm               : 6.13.2
    OS                : Windows 10
```

How to solve this issue